# JAVA - Is there possible pass a servlet value received to a .java file, but in another project?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

good afternoon. I have a .JSP file that send a value to a servlet file. I have another project, where there is a java file in that i want to get this servlet value received by .JSP file.

My question is if is there possible pass this servlet value to this .java file in another project ? Or can i send by .JSP file directly ?

I created a Java Class in my Web Application, but now, how can i pass the servlet parameter to this java class ?

I will put the code down here:

Servlet code:

```
public class ServletJava extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

     /*I WANT TO INSTANCE THE PARAMETER HERE TO SEND TO OTHER CLASS*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

The Class java:

```
public class RecebeServlet {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      /*I WANT RECEIVE THE PARAMETER HERE !! */
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. How are your projects structured (files, folders, etc)? How exactly does the value you want to pass look like? It is always a good idea to post a [minimal, complete and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, it's another project(folder and file) that i'm programming on netbeans. One is Web Application and the other is a Java Application

Comment: Do you have a `pom.xml` or a `build.gradle` file in your projects?

Comment: When i look throw netbeans, i found nothing. But, when i go on the folder project. I found the `build`, but, just on .xml extension only. The `pom` there isn't on the folder

Comment: Do you really need to have the two classes in two separate projects? If not, you could simply move (or copy) the class from one project to the other? Although this is not best practice, it would avoid getting ourselves in the troubles of dependency management

Comment: Ok, i did something that you said. But now, how can i pass a servlet parameter to a normal class java ? I will update the description of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably bad practice to have a class with only one main mathod. I am sure that you can divide the logic from that class into several methods instead of having one giant `main`.

But anyway, since you asked: Just call your `main` method as you would call any static method:

```
String[] args = new String[1];
args[0] = yourValue;
RecebeServlet.main(args);
```

But again, please consider refactoring your `RecebeServlet` class. You do not want to have program logic in your main method.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks. I discorver also that i can set directly from .JSP file, without the need of servlet. However, thank you so much !